# Hackage name collision while using stack solver with extra-deps

Tags: haskell, package, cabal, haskell-stack

Well it turns out that my app name is the same as one of the packages that is uploaded to hackage, so when I try to resolver extra dependencies using `stack solver --resolver lts 7.12`, I get the following error:

```
$ stack solver --resolver lts-7.12
Using configuration file: stack.yaml
Using cabal packages:
- html-parse.cabal

Using resolver: lts-7.12
Using compiler: ghc-8.0.1
Asking cabal to calculate a build plan...
Trying with packages from lts-7.12 as hard constraints...
Attempt failed.

>>>> Cabal errors begin
cabal.exe: Could not resolve dependencies:
next goal: html-parse (user goal)
rejecting: html-parse-0.2.0.0, 0.1.0.0 (global constraint requires ==0.0.0.3)
trying: html-parse-0.0.0.3
next goal: hunit (dependency of html-parse-0.0.0.3)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
<<<< Cabal errors end

Could not parse cabal-install errors:

>>>> Cabal errors begin
cabal.exe: Could not resolve dependencies:
next goal: html-parse (user goal)
rejecting: html-parse-0.2.0.0, 0.1.0.0 (global constraint requires ==0.0.0.3)
trying: html-parse-0.0.0.3
next goal: hunit (dependency of html-parse-0.0.0.3)
Dependency tree exhaustively searched.
<<<< Cabal errors end
```

My app/package name in .cabal file is `html-parse` and the current version is 0.0.0.3. It looks like my own package is listed as a dependency with a constraint of `==0.0.0.3`, but there is another pacakge on hackage that has the same name but different versions.

Can I somehow solve this issue without renaming my own app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the [Cabal user guide](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#package-names-and-versions) (emphasis mine):

> Package names and versions
>
> All packages have a name, e.g. “HUnit”. *Package names are assumed to be unique*. Cabal package names can use letters, numbers and hyphens, but not spaces. The namespace for Cabal packages is flat, not hierarchical.

Accordingly, the *Cabal* library doesn't have a feature for handling package name conflicts, and neither do *cabal-install* nor *stack*. That being so, you will have to rename your package.

P.S.: I am deliberately not considering seriously the possibility of setting up your project to use a [private Hackage](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/nonstandard_project_init/#private-hackage) that excludes the homonymous package, both because I don't know how it would play out in practice and because it is vastly more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and edits. I was just thinking that my core app will not be considered a package, but now I see that everything has to be a package in terms of cabal in order to build multipackage projects with libs and such.